# Gaussian/Normal plots from a data distribution in scientific notation

Tags: pgfplots, distributions

I am new to Tex and trying to plot a gaussian distribution from a set of values. I have the following set of values and would like to plot a normal distribution for them.

2.9954E-09  3.1314E-09  3.1155E-09  3.0940E-09  2.8861E-09  3.0875E-09  2.9685E-09  3.0532E-09  2.9003E-09  3.0931E-09

I have tried using the sample code but can't figue out where to input my values.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, 
  domain=0:6, 
  samples=10,
  ymin=0,
  axis lines*=left, 
  xlabel=$x$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, 
  width=11cm,
  xtick=\empty, 
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major,
  hide y axis
  ]

 \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};

\pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{gauss(1,3,1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\valueB{gauss(2,3,1)}
\draw [gray] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,\valueA)
    (axis cs:5,0) -- (axis cs:5,\valueA);
\draw [gray] (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,\valueB)
    (axis cs:4,0) -- (axis cs:4,\valueB);
\draw [yshift=1.4cm, latex-latex](axis cs:2, 0) -- node [fill=white] {$0.683$} (axis cs:4, 0);
\draw [yshift=0.3cm, latex-latex](axis cs:1, 0) -- node [fill=white] {$0.954$} (axis cs:5, 0);

\node[below] at (axis cs:1, 0)  {$\mu - 2\sigma$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:2, 0)  {$\mu - \sigma$}; 
\node[below] at (axis cs:3, 0)  {$\mu$}; 
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Your assistance will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A Gaussian distribution needs the mean and variance, so put the data into tikz arrays and compute the average and sample variance with foreach loops.

Comment: @John Kormylo: thanks but your answer is still very vague for me to understand. could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ksnf3000, if my answer was helpful please think about [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it) and/or [accepting it](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). Otherwise please edit your question to make more clear what your exact question is. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You mean something like this ...

(Please note that I have multiplied all given values by 10^9, which doesn't change anything here because you don't show any values.)

```
% here are your data, just multiplied by 10^9
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
    2.9954
    3.1314
    3.1155
    3.094
    2.8861
    3.0875
    2.9685
    3.0532
    2.9003
    3.0931
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use at least this `compat' level so there is no need to prefix
        % coordinates with "axis cs:"
        compat=1.11,
        %
        /pgf/declare function={
            % `mu' and `sigma' where calculated in Excel using above data
            mu=3.03250;
            sigma=0.0894182;
            % declare gaussian function
            gauss(\x)=1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-mu)^2)/(2*sigma^2));
            % precalculate some values
            yA=gauss(mu-2*sigma);
            yB=gauss(mu-sigma);
            % constant to simply change calculating `domain' and x axis limits
            C=2.5;
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % set axis limits and `domain'
            xmin=mu-C*sigma,
            xmax=mu+C*sigma,
            ymin=0,
            domain=mu-C*sigma:mu+C*sigma,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % nothing changed here
            samples=100,
            axis lines*=left,
            xlabel=$x$,
            every axis x label/.style={
                at=(current axis.right of origin),
                anchor=west,
            },
            height=5cm,
            width=11cm,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            axis on top,
            hide y axis,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % use ticks just at the coordinates of the first `\addplot' ...
            xtick=data,
            % and show the below labels for these ticks
            xticklabels={
                $\mu - 2\sigma$,
                $\mu - \sigma$,
                $\mu$
            },
        ]

        % just a dummy plot used for the `xticklabels'
            \addplot [draw=none,fill=none] coordinates {
                (mu-2*sigma,0)
                (mu-sigma,0)
                (mu,0)
            };
        % plot the data point and the corresponding gauss curve
            \addplot [only marks,cyan]
                table [x index=0,y expr=0] {data.txt};
            \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x)};

        % add some lines and labels
            % draw vertical lines
            \draw [gray]
                (mu-2*sigma,0) -- coordinate (A left)  (mu-2*sigma,yA)
                (mu+2*sigma,0) -- coordinate (A right) (mu+2*sigma,yA);
            \draw [gray]
                (mu-sigma,0)   -- coordinate (B left)  (mu-sigma,yB)
                (mu+sigma,0)   -- coordinate (B right) (mu+sigma,yB);
            % draw labels
            \draw [latex-latex]
                (A left) -- node [fill=white] {$0.954$} (A right);
            \draw [latex-latex]
                (B left) -- node [fill=white] {$0.683$} (B right);

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]