# Gaussian distribution of physics data

Tags: pgfplots

I have to make a gaussian distribution of some physics data using pgfplots. the data are 5, all between 21.00 and 22.00 with mu=21.52 e sigma=0.013. so i want to draw the function of the gaussian and have a mark corresponding to my data (this is the part i can do) may i have some help?

```
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom,axis y line=none,,xmin=21,xmax=22, title=Normal data distribution]
\addplot {gauss(x,21,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you give us some more information, i.e., show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you already have and add a description of the concrete problem you have? Please do it by editing your question. Maybe we also need the date or a minimal example for it.

Comment: This is only a code snippet and still not a *working* example. Please have a look at the link in my first comment.

Comment: I know, 'couse it keeps giving me errors such  as "PGF math error: sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit0'...\end{axis}"

Comment: Does one of these answers help you to solve the problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333366, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383403.

Comment: You need to remember that the default domain is -5 to 5, so with `xmin=21,xmax=22` you wont get any data points in the axis. Set e.g. `domain=21:22`, or whatever you need.

Comment: Working does not mean running without error. But as long as the example isn't complete, we cannot reproduce problems. Please make it complete, starting with `\documentclass` and including all packages and settings needed to reproduce the problem etc.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

your demand for drawing Gaussian function is at a limits of `pgfplots` package ability to drawing it :-(. if i correctly decode meaning of parameters in your `gauss` function, than i obtain:

[image]

this images can is draw in three segments. in one you cross mentioned ability of `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%#3:  sigma
                                  %#2:  mu (expected value)
                                  %#1:  variable
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(#1-#2)*(#1-#2)/(#3*#3)/2)}%
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom, 
             axis y line=none,
             tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
             extra x ticks = {21.52},
             extra x tick labels = {$\mu$},
             title={Normal data distribution},
             mark=none, samples=30
             every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, color=red!50}
             ]
\addplot[domain=21:21.3]                {gauss(x,21.52,0.013)};
\addplot[samples=400, domain=21.3:21.7] {gauss(x,21.52,0.013)};
\addplot[domain=21.7:22]                {gauss(x,21.52,0.013)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which of the many changes actually rang the bell.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)*(#1-#2))/(2*#3*#3))}%
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom, axis y line=none, title={Normal data distribution}]
\addplot[mark=none, domain=21:22] {gauss(x,21,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]