# Improvement of my pgf plots figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to make a NMR spectroscopy chart, till now i have this:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[   scale only axis=true,
                    width=.8\textwidth,
                    height=.3\textwidth,
                    tick align=outside,
                    tick pos=left,
                    xmin=0, xmax=160,
                    ymin=0, ymax=100,
                    xticklabels={9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0},
                    yticklabels={0},
                    xlabel={PPM},
                    title={NMR Spectroscopy},
                    ]
        \addplot[black,domain=0:160] {8};
        \addplot+[ycomb,black,no markers] plot coordinates{
            (135,95)
                (136,45)
                (134,40)
                (110,47)
                (111,20)
                (109,42)
                (108,18)
                (40,19)
        };
        \node at (123,85) {\small $CH_3$};
        \node at (123,75) {\small \textsl{Triplet}};
        \node at (110,65) {\small $CH_2$};
        \node at (110,55) {\small \textsl{Quartet}};
        \node at (40,45) {\small $OH$};
        \node at (40,35) {\small \textsl{Singlet}};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and it looks like this:
[image]

what I want is this:

[image]

and my questions are:

1. How to delete the plot between axis and "ground"?
2. How to delete ticks on the Y axis?
3. How to add a half ticks between majors on X axis?

Comment: You can use ````ytick style={draw=none},```` in the ````axis```` environment to prevent ticks form being displayed.

Comment: That doesn't worked

Comment: It worked for me after adding a comma following ````yticklabels={0}```` in your MWE

Comment: Ok yeah, that comma, was a problem, this part is solved thanks

Comment: @MichałSzymankiewicz, do you have the measured peak-curve available as image or pdf? If so, please add its screenshot to your question, so we can show you an other route towards your graphic.

Comment: @MS-SPO no, I haven't. I've just wanted to make an overview chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it to obtain a `stylized` spectrum.

Ad 2: Was already answered.

Ad 3: Add `minor x tick num=1,` to have 1 minor between two major ticks

Ad 1: change `ymin=-10,` AND `\addplot[black,domain=0:160] {0};`

**Result**:

[image: result]

To obtain really peak-like structures, i.e. Dirac pulses (decay) convoluted with Gaussians (detector), you'd need to calculate AND superimpose (add) several, 8 in your case, Gaussians. To do so:

- use a normal x-y plot, i.e. without `\addplot[black,domain=0:160] {0};`
- calculate by rewriting approaches as given below, where one component takes amplitude, x-position and have a fixed very small sigma
- along this route

  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
  }
- [Gaussian distribution of physics data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390226/gaussian-distribution-of-physics-data)
- [How to get this Gaussian Plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330412/how-to-get-this-gaussian-plot)
- [How to create a gaussian curve with pgfplot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79228/how-to-create-a-gaussian-curve-with-pgfplot?rq=1)
- query [[pgfplots] peak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpgfplots%5D%20peak)
- query [[pgfplots] gaussian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpgfplots%5D%20gaussian)

**Code**:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[   scale only axis=true,
                    width=.8\textwidth,
                    height=.3\textwidth,
                    tick align=outside,
                    tick pos=left,
                    xmin=0, xmax=160,
                    ymin=-10, ymax=100,                 % <<<
                    minor x tick num=1,                 % <<<
                    xticklabels={9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0},
                    yticklabels={0},
                    ytick style={draw=none},            % from comments
                    xlabel={PPM},
                    title={Stylized NMR Spectroscopy},  % <<<
                    ]
        \addplot[black,domain=0:160] {0};               % <<<
        \addplot+[ycomb,black,no markers] plot coordinates{
                (135,95)
                (136,45)
                (134,40)
                (110,47)
                (111,20)
                (109,42)
                (108,18)
                (40,19)
        };
        \node at (123,85) {\small $CH_3$};
        \node at (123,75) {\small \textsl{Triplet}};
        \node at (110,65) {\small $CH_2$};
        \node at (110,55) {\small \textsl{Quartet}};
        \node at (40,45) {\small $OH$};
        \node at (40,35) {\small \textsl{Singlet}};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```