# How to draw location line and width at half maximum line in tikz/pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

I am attempting to draw a gaussian distribution using pgfplots in tikz.
I would like to put a horizontal line illustrating the standard deviation, a horizontal line, in this example at x=0.5 - 1.5, y = whatever the function equals at those locations.

How might I do that?

right now I have code that gives me something like this:

[image]

```
%plot of gaussian distribution
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%gauss function {loc, std}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaussx}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{exp(-#2*((x-#1)^2)}%
}
                    
%gauss function {x, loc, std}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{exp(-#3*((#1-#2)^2)}%
}
      
\begin{document}    

                 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

  \begin{axis}[
      no markers, domain=-6:6,
      samples=100,
      axis lines*=middle,
      xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2}$,
      height=5cm, width=7cm,
      xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
      restrict y to domain=--6:6]

      \addplot [very thick, teal] {gaussx(1, 1)};
    
      \draw[thin, red] (axis cs:1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}); %draws a vertical line, but at x=4
     
     %I thought what I want should look like this?
     %\draw[thin, red] (axis cs:1, gauss{1.5, 1, 1}\pgfmathresult) 
     %                     -- (axis cs:1, gauss{.5, 1, 1}\pgfmathresult); 
                    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

*I figure it will be part of the correct syntax of the command I want, but in case it isn't, bonus points if you can help me make the vertical line terminate at the peak.*

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I have understood your question right, but do you search for something similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333366/95441?

Comment: yes, yes I do. I'm really just trying to get my head around 1) extracting the result of a pgf math function, and 2) transforming a coordinate into axis coordinates on a plot. But I think the code you linked allows me to copy lines that do both

Comment: @AndrewMicallef  please see if the answer below meets the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%gauss function {loc, std}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gaussx}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{exp(-#2*((x-#1)^2)}%
}

%gauss function {x, loc, std}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
    \pgfmathparse{exp(-#3*((#1-#2)^2)}%
}

\begin{document}    
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        
        \begin{axis}[
            no markers, domain=-6:6, samples=100,
            axis lines*=middle,
            xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2}$,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.west),anchor=south,rotate=90},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.south),anchor=north},
            height=5cm, width=7cm,
            xtick=\empty, 
            ytick=\empty,
            enlargelimits=false, 
%           clip=false, 
            axis on top,
            grid = major]
            
            \addplot [very thick, teal] {gaussx(1, 1)};
            \addplot [fill=none, draw=blue, domain=0.5:1.5] {gaussx(1,1)} \closedcycle;
            \draw[red] (axis cs:1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
I f
```